# How to check if object has method in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use the same piece of code for managing multiple entities but it might be a little different depending if it has some method or not. Thats why I need to check if object has method by name. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use `is_callable`:

```
if (is_callable([$entity, 'methodName']))
    doSomething();
```

A cleaner approach is to check for the class of an object with `instanceof`. Because methods will come and go, but the character of an object is determined by its class:

```
if ($entity instanceof \Some\Bundle\Entity\Class)
    doSomething();
```

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with Symfony, it's basic PHP thing: use **method_exists** PHP function.

```
bool method_exists ( mixed $object , string $method_name )
```

[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

While this is a perfectly fine way to go around it, you might want to look into interfaces as an alternative: [PHP Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

If you do decide to use them, you can just check if object is an instance of your interface:

```
interface MyAwesomeInterface
{
    public function myFunction();
}


if ($myObject instanceof MyAwesomeInterface) {
    $myObject->myFunction();
}
```